# SQL: How to combine two columns with punctuation?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I would like to combine two columns into one and separate by a '/' using SQL statement

Currently, I could only do this.

```
Select A.Marks, Q.NoOfAnsBox FROM AnswerTable AS A INNER JOIN QuestionTable AS 
Q WHERE A.QuestionID = Q.QuestionID
```

With the output:

```
Marks NoOfAnsBox    
3     5    
2     5
```

May I know if it is possible to output it as one column as follows?

```
Marks    
3/5    
2/5
```

I tried convert the integers into string and perform concatenation but failed to obtain the desired result

```
Select (CONVERT(A.Marks, Char(50)) + '/' + Convert(Q.NoOfAnsBox,Char(50))) As     
Marks FROM AnswerTable AS A INNER JOIN QuestionTable AS Q WHERE A.QuestionID = 
Q.QuestionID
```

```
Marks    
8    
7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mysql use the `CONCAT()` function to concatenate strings as `+` acts differently here than in other RDBMS's:

```
Select CONCAT(A.Marks, '/', Q.NoOfAnsBox) As Marks 
FROM AnswerTable AS A 
    INNER JOIN QuestionTable AS Q ON A.QuestionID = Q.QuestionID
```

Also consider changing your "WHERE" to an "ON". In your case they are synonymous, but things could get ugly if you swap your `INNER` join to a `LEFT OUTER` join and forget to monkey with the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Also, if you want to write portable SQL, ANSI SQL syntax requires the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select CONCAT(A.Marks, '/', Q.NoOfAnsBox) AS Marks FROM AnswerTable AS A INNER JOIN QuestionTable AS 
Q WHERE A.QuestionID = Q.QuestionID
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `Concat()` function as follows

```
 Select CONCAT(A.Marks, '/', Q.NoOfAnsBox) AS Marks 
 FROM AnswerTable AS A INNER JOIN QuestionTable AS Q 
 WHERE A.QuestionID = Q.QuestionID
```